# Code snippet to change system date and time in java

Tags: java, datetime

I have a requirement to change the system date and time, and i am aware of the **"date -s"** command that will do the job on the command prompt. But however when i try adding the same command in my java code, it doesn't seem to be working. Following is the lines of code that i am expecting it to work:

```
        String value = "2015-04-12 20:26:14";
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(value);
        value = dateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println("for debugging");
        final Process dateProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c date "+value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf(' ')));
        System.out.println("step 1");
         dateProcess.waitFor();

        System.out.println("step 2");
        dateProcess.exitValue();
        final Process timeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c time "+value.substring(value.lastIndexOf(' ')+1));
        timeProcess.waitFor();
        timeProcess.exitValue();
```

when i execute the above code snippet being an administrator, the program is hung up at  dateProcess.waitFor(); line.

please suggest me a corrective measure for this to get working.

Comment: Did you try to override method returning time? [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=234)
I don't know if it's possible to do the things like this using Java API

Comment: Using the fake system clock does not help as the application requires me to change the date and time at system clock level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look to be missing the **-s** argument in the date and time commands, so your waitFor() method never returns because it's waiting for user input.

Try changing

```
final Process dateProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c date "+value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf(' ')));
```

to

```
final Process dateProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c date -s "+value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf(' ')));
```

and the same for your time command. (Assuming this is Windows only).

Comment: I did try "date -s" in the code. But the concern here is if really java is able to execute the command "cmd /c" as an administrator. I guess we need to be sure on this part. Any suggestions on this please,

Comment: ...exec("cmd /c whoami"); should display the user it is running as.

Comment: in windows 7 admin model i tried  "cmd /c start whoami" it works, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The code was missing "start" hence the command prompt was never called

final Process dateProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start date -s "+value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf(' ')));

after adding "start" i am getting the expected result.

Thanks for the help, Cheers!!